# How to inflate layout from custom view java class? NOT from XML

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying set Recycle View programatically please help.

```
public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_item /- how to do it here from custom view  class?/, parent, false);
    RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewViewHolder;
}
```

Comment: The verb "inflate" refers to loading resources. There is no concept of "inflate layout... NOT from XML". If you want to create an instance of a custom view class, use a constructor on that custom view class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the constructor for your custom view:

```
public RecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = new MyCustomView(parent.getContext());
    RecyclerViewViewHolder recyclerViewViewHolder = new RecyclerViewViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewViewHolder;
}
```